# How to make that the folder name will be 001,002,003?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
else if (currentLightningFolderPath != null)
{
    int currentLightningEndFrame = processedFrames;
    string frameRange = $"[{currentLightningStartFrame:D4}-{currentLightningEndFrame:D4}]";
    string lightningFolderName = $"Lightning{"D3"}_{frameRange}";
    Directory.Move(currentLightningFolderPath, Path.Combine(selectedFolderPath, lightningFolderName));
    currentLightningFolderPath = null;
    framesCaptured = 0; // Reset the counter
}
```

I thought the "D3" will do it but the folders names on the hard disk are:

LightningD3_ and the next one also start as LightningD3_

and I want the folders to start with Lightning001_ then Lightning002_ and so on.

Comment: What did you expect `string lightningFolderName = $"Lightning{"D3"}_...";` to do? You're using string interpolation, but your interpolating another literal string.

Comment: `"Lightning" + <some interger value>.ToString("D3")` will give you strings like "Lighting001" etc.

Comment: You need to use a loop or a global number for generating the sequence number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$"Lightning{"D3"}_{frameRange}"
```

`D3` is a format specifier, telling the compiler that the number should be printed with 3 digits.

You missed the part where you told the compiler *which number* you wanted to be printed that way. Instead, you added quotes to make it compile. But that only means you get the fixed string "D3" instead of a formatted variable you want.

```
$"Lightning{yourVariable:D3}_{frameRange}"
```

It is your job, to have and fill `yourVariable` with the value you want.